# How to get a list of non duplicate values from one property

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<Employee> employees` which contains the property `CategoryID`. I want to extract these categories in `List<int> employeeCategories`.

I tried this but I get duplicate categories:

```
List<int> employeeCategories = employees.Select(x => x.CategoryID).ToList();
```

I want all these categories but not duplicate.

I've been trying to do this:

```
List<int> employeeCategories = employees.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryID).Select(x => x.First()).Select(x => x.CategoryID).ToList();
```

Is there a simpler and cleaner way to achieve this? Am I using correctly the `GroupBy` method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Honestly, that is the way I do it too.  Using the LINQ extension Distinct() will often not work the way I want it too.

Comment: You can simplify that to `GroupBy(x => x.CategoryID).Select(g => g.Key).ToList();`.  The result of `GroupBy` is a `IGrouping` where each item has a `Key` that is the unique value of whatever you grouped on.

Comment: @juharr Interesting. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what `Distinct()` is for. It removes all the duplicate entries.

```
List<int> employeeCategories = employees.Select(x => x.CategoryID).Distinct().ToList();
```